# Как убрать BOM из файла?

Tags: файлы, unix, unicode

Как консольно (в Unix-like окружении) удалить BOM (byte-order mark, непечатаемый символ в самом начале файла, являющийся необязательной меткой юникода) из файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, с помощью awk:

```
awk '{if(NR==1)sub(/^\xef\xbb\xbf/, "");print}' < oldfile > newfile
```

Comment: Если файл без BOM,  он не будет поврежден?

Comment: Нет - регулярное выражение заменяет именно последовательность из трёх конкретных байт `\xef\xbb\xbf` именно из начала файла на пустоту. Если их там нет - ничего не произойдёт, файл останется неизменным. Можно проверить.

Comment: Прошло полтора года, появился ещё комментарий. Наверное, стоит отметить, что так удаляется bom только от UTF-8, что это безопасно и что его наличие как раз опасно, например тем,  что блокирует shebang. )

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `sed`:

```
$ sed -e '1s/^\xef\xbb\xbf//' < bomfile > newfile
```

Если заранее известно, что файл содержит BOM, то можно использовать `dd`:

```
$ dd if=bomfile of=newfile bs=3 skip=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Если точно знаете, что файл с BOM

```
$ tail -c +4 <bomfile >newfile
```

эффективно копирует все, пропустив первые 3 байта (см. `man tail` for details)

Comment: а если BOM в файле на самом деле нет - он будет повреждён