# Почему не работает iconv()

Tags: php, iconv

Нужно исправить кодировку для всех сообщений

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if (mb_detect_encoding($row['title']) == 'ASCII')
        $emailer_messages[$row['id']] = iconv("ASCII", "UTF-8", $row['title']);
    else
        $emailer_messages[$row['id']] = $row['title'];
}
```

однако когда проверяю $emailer_messages значения в нём по прежнему в ASCII

Comment: Исправлять ничего не надо. Надо задать желаемую кодировку с помощью mysql_set_charset() после коннекта

Comment: Так же проверьте кодировку html страницы

Comment: mysql_set_charset() не помогла, всё так же большая часть сообщений в ASCII

Comment: Значит надо исправлять исходную кодировку, а не ставить костыль. И что такое "часть сообщений в ASCII"?

Comment: База данных в UTF-8, когда я проверяю что приходит из базы по запросу, то часть в UTF-8 а часть в ASCII. Например я прямо в цикле вывожу кодировку в файл :  file_put_contents('1.txt', var_export(mb_detect_encoding($row['title']), true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

Answer (score 1):

ASCII - это подмножество UTF-8. Если ваш файл целиком и полностью состоит из символов ASCII, он побайтово аналогичен тако му же файлу формата UTF-8.

> Для номеров с U+0000 по U+007F кодировка UTF-8 полностью соответствует
>   7-битному US-ASCII c 0 в старшем бите и занимает один байт.

Comment: однако в таком файле может присутствовать BOM - тогда побайтово аналогичен он не будет. см., например, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/433935/ про то, как убрать BOM из файла.